Trouble Connecting PostgreSQL Client in Windows to Server in WSL (Ubuntu 20.04)
Encountering difficulty establishing a connection between the PostgreSQL client in Windows and the PostgreSQL server running in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
Error Encountered:
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Environment Details:

WSL Version: Ubuntu 20.04
PostgreSQL Client Version (in WSL): [16.2]
PostgreSQL Version (in Windows): [16.2]

Despite ensuring that the PostgreSQL server is configured to accept TCP/IP connections, the connection attempt fails consistently. Seeking guidance on resolving this connectivity issue. Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be appreciated. Thank you!
The user might have tried configuring the PostgreSQL server in WSL to accept TCP/IP connections, but despite their efforts, they are consistently encountering the "Connection refused" error when attempting to connect the PostgreSQL client in Windows to the server in WSL. They expected the connection to be established successfully, but instead, they received the error message mentioned above.

You could try using the private IP of your Windows machine instead of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1". This might resolve your error.
